# When we compile a source code that contains a 'main' without linking, why can't we run it?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc, compilation

I am learning about compiling process and I know that linking is mainly used to link a binary file which contains a 'main' function with other binary files that contain other helper functions that are used in our main functions.

However when I try to run an object file with the code:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the -c command in gcc on Ubuntu, I try to run it and I get the error:

> "bash: ./source.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Comment: Object files are not directly executable.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I know but my I would like to understand why. Why can't they be executed even if the source file that they are compiled from DOES NOT link top any kind of external file ?

Comment: you need linkage for standard functions, like `printf`, and such. and even if you don't use them, you need an _entrypoint_, startup code to initialize heap, stack...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I do not use the printf function but I do not even #include the stdio and any other thing. Even if I do not include anything in my code do I still need linkeage for standard function ? If yes then why do I need them ?

Comment: Well the operating system told you it didn't recognize it the file format as an executable. That's WHY!

Comment: I think the error message comtains a pretty good clue: the result of  `-c` is not in the rigjt format to be executed. (Neither is the output of `gcc -S`, although arguably it has been "compiled".)

Comment: Useful reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thank you Scott. A helpful answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  That is certainly not what the question is abut. You CAN write a program that does not communicate with the exterior. The fact that it has no practical purpose is completely irrelevant to the question that I asked.

Comment: Because `main` is not the startup code of a program.

Comment: @Olaf What is the startup code of a program ?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  Why have I been blocked from asking questions ???

Comment: @yoyo_fun: `man execl` will give you a pretty good overview of what happens prior to `main` be called (and also what happens after `main` returns). `execl` is crucial because, according to Posix, once the shell has identified which executable image is to be run, "the shell executes the utility in a separate utility environment... with actions equivalent to calling the execl() function... with the path argument set to the pathname resulting from the search, arg0 set to the command name, and the remaining execl() arguments set to the command arguments (if any) and the null terminator."

Comment: @yoyo_fun: Learn how to search: `c startup code` shows links to multiple useful sites.

Comment: @yoyo_fun: A program which has no effect to the environment, i.e. no **observable behaviour** can be reduced to no existence. Which the compiler is allowed to do.

Comment: @Olaf No, it is still a program that can put the processor to do all kinds of operations on all kinds of operators in the memory and in the registries. And for this a program does not need to import any library. It can do mathematical operations on numbers that are hardcoded. This does not mean the program does not exist. And the question 'why a program needs to be linked even if it does not import absolutely anything?' is still a valid and interesting question.

Comment: @yoyo_fun: Please read the standard!

Comment: Why the `c++` tag since you are talking of a C program ?

Comment: @yoyo_fun: if some answer (perhaps mine's) fits your expectations, please accept it.

Comment: This is a convention that was define. The executable needs a place to start, so someone came up with calling it main in C/C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read Levine's [*Linkers & Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/).

Read about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Try compiling with `gcc -v` (you'll see what are the actual programs used: `cc1` to [compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) C code into some assembler, `as` to [assemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler) that into some object file, [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) & [`collect2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))). Look also at the generated assembler file with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O`. Notice that `gcc` knows about (and compiles *specially*) the `main` function. And the starting point of your executable is provided by some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0), etc (it is *not* `main` but some `_start` routine coded in assembler which calls your `main`....).

[Object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code) are not the same as [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). The executable contains stuff like [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) and the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), or some way to [dynamically link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) it as a [shared object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) (and you need to link your `source.o` -compiled from your empty `main` in `source.c`- into an executable because of that).

On Linux, play with [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) & [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) (on some existing binaries, and also on your `source.o` object file)

See also [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html), [Linux assembly howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/), and (to understand about `libc.so`) Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) ...

<sup>(you need to read entire books to understand the details; I gave some references)</sup>

Look also into Common Lisp & [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/). Its compiler has a very different model (really different from C).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.... many people here seem to be very rude to the beginner programmers, even if my question was not asked before I am downvoted to oblivion.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have a bootstrap.  you are in this chicken and egg problem.

The code (for that function) is there, but there are assumptions, first and foremost you need a stack.  Depending on the architecture your return address may be on that stack for example.  The return value may be on that stack.  The C language itself doesnt provide for that directly in the language there is always at least a little bit of assembly or some other language required in order to "bootstrap" your function.  For example in ARM for gnu:

bs.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov sp,#0x8000
    bl main
    b .
```

so.c

```
int main ( void )
{
    return(0);
}
```

For ARM the function is complete the instructions dont need to be modified by the linker. but there is no address space defined, either specified or the disassembler assumes zero as the address for this object, but it is an object not a loadable binary.

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

now if we add the bootstrap and link to some address we get a real, executable, program

```
00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <main>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <_start+0x8>

0000800c <main>:
    800c:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

It doesnt mean one couldnt craft an operating system nor an environment where you could load functions in this way, using the compilers object output.  But that is the reason for the word chain, tool chain.  Compiler makes assembly language, the assembler assembles the assembly language, combined with other necessary objects (bootstrap plus compiler libraries plus C libraries, etc) the linker defines the address spaces for everything and modifies the code/data as needed to resolve externals.  A sequence or chain of events to get the final result.

Comment: for this specific example didnt need the stack pointer to be initialized, generally that is the bare minimum, stack pointer and branch to the C language entry point.  REAL C programs with .data and .bss other things need to happen in the bootstrap.

Comment: as well as a proper system call to exit, which is operating system dependent how that happens.

Answer (score -2):

Even the most basic commands like `exit` aren't directly in the language and need to be linked.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit

Comment: OP doesn't use any functions from any libraries.  In the example code quoted above, there are no functions that need to be linked.

Comment: If a program is freestanding then you don't need to link any external functions at all.

Comment: But you do need to link the system entry point that eventually calls main().

Comment: @ScottMermelstein - No way to answer both comments but, you're both wrong - there are external functions that are needed, setup/teardown of the environment for example.  Look at the machinations necessary in an assembly program to make it free standing and compare to the `.s` output from a `gcc -s source.c`

Comment: @bace1000 - see my comment to Scott

Comment: @ryyker Since when has `exit` been a keyword?

Comment: @bace1000 - my mistake, it is a function. I never use it, but have seen it, I misspoke before verifying what it really was.